# Can't get toggle script to work in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get the below code to work in WordPress, but I cannot get it to work. The HTML and CSS displays properly, but the click doesn't do anything. I cannot figure out how to get jQuery to work. The code itself does work ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A79JG/)). Thanks in advance for your help!

In my header:

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Carelink</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/carelink.css">


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .bbb { background-color: blue; }
    .aaa { background-color: red; }
</style>
<script>
$("#click").click(function() {
    $("#ccc").toggle().animate();
    $(this).toggleClass('bbb aaa');
});
</script>
```

On the page:

```
<div id="click" class="bbb">click</div>
<div id="ccc" style="display:none;">hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery instead $. $ symbol is reserved in Wordpress.

Comment: That's good to know about the $.  I absolutely don't know how to do it in query though.

Comment: Just wrap your javascript code in this frame
jQuery(function($){
//your code here
});

Comment: Winner, winner!  Thank you so much!  I tucked this away for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't override the `header.php` to include Javascript.

Instead use `functions.php`. Here you'll find more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: You also can ask Wordpress programming questions here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com